# Does the D-bus need a UI or it can also be used in command line tools?

Tags: linux, x11, dbus

It seems the D-bus is a very convinent way to communicate proccesses in linux. My question is does it need a UI/x11 started before or it can also be used in command line tools without UI/x11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing D-Bus needs in order to work is the D-Bus server daemon itself. This is invoked via `dbus-launch` which can be integrated into shell startup scripts in the event that the X init system isn't used. Additionally, applications can attempt to execute `dbus-launch` themselves in order to either attempt to use a session bus created at login or to create a session bus for the application's own use. Naturally the first option (or the first result of the second option) is preferred since it will use fewer resources overall.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. The system D-Bus (launched as `dbus --system`) is started before the X server.

Further examinations of the process by `ldd` does not show any dependency on X:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/dbus-daemon 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff669ff000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f27cd14e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f27ccefc000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f27cccf4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f27cc92b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f27cd378000)
```